# php file_get_content wrong response encoding for xml

Tags: php, netbeans, encoding, file-get-contents

I have the following code:

```
$s = file_get_contents(someurl);
```

the response is an XML but for some reason it's appended and prepended by a weird symbol:

```
� <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Response>
 </Response>
�
```

I tried different types of encoding but no luck.

The strange thing is i'm working locally with wamp, but on my Nginx+PHP-FPM it's working properly.
*maybe a netbeans issue?

### EDIT:

running:

```
mb_detect_encoding($str)
```

on wamp return UTF-8 and on NginX (where the response is ok) is : ASCII....
what am i missing??

Comment: All of the lines have their first character cut off?

Comment: Is the url you're getting the content from some public url or something you're outputting? You're not telling much...

Comment: Its probably not netbeans but your php is encoding the file not as utf-8. Is your php file saved as utf-8? Is php configured to use utf-8? Did you told the browser that the source is utf-8? Is the source indeed utf-8?

Comment: 1. Not all characters are cut off (i cut it off because if i'll leave it you won't see any text..) 2. url is 3rd party private 3. yes...everything is set to utf-8

Comment: @DannyValariola you're not supposed to cut anything off, you're supposed to use code formatting option for code

Answer (score 0):

By 'the response', do you mean the result from the file_get_contents function, as read into $s?

Assuming this is the case, it may be that the server that is sending the response to the 'someurl' URL is sending an HTTP header that is changing the encoding that php is trying to read the result in, resulting in this weirdness.

You can use $http_response_header as described here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

to find out the http headers that were sent along with the response to the url to try and diagnose the problem further.

Comment: nice try buy no luck...6 => string 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' (length=37)